# Как сделать простой Random 1-5 в textView на экран

Tags: java, android

Как сделать  простой Random 
(выпадающие одно число от 1 до 5  )

чтобы записывалось в textView на экран

Comment: И что у вас не получается? Есть какой то код уже?

Comment: Random random = new Random(5);


        resText2.setText("" + random);

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/random.php

Answer (score 1):

Вам следовало использовать не класс Random, а метод `Math.random()`, для генерации случайного числа.

**Задание диапазонов и генерация**

```
int start = 1; // Начальное значение диапазона - "от"
int end = 5; // Конечное значение диапазона - "до"

// Генерация случайного числа в заданном диапазоне
int randomNumber = start + (int) (Math.random() * end);
```

Пример, в котором при нажатию на кнопку, на экран будет выводится случайное число.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.random;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    TextView resText2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resText2 = findViewById(R.id.resText2);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int start = 1; // Начальное значение диапазона - "от"
                int end = 5; // Конечное значение диапазона - "до"

                // Генерация случайного числа в заданном диапазоне
                int randomNumber = start + (int) (Math.random() * end);

                // Вывод на экран
                resText2.setText("" + randomNumber);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Тут будет случайное число"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/resText2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```